# Springboot Ehcache load data

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache

- Service using SpringBoot, Maven, MongoDB, Ehcache.
- Service requires a fast and frequently cache server, so eventually, I chose Ehcache.
- All the cache will be called almost at the same frequency so there are no hot cold data in this case.
- The original data in MongoDB will be updated every day by a timer service, so what I do is to load all the updated data to Ehcache every day.
- Each item in this data has a connection with each other, like you use one to find the relevant Ids of the other. So if one cache is updated, but the other one hasn't, then you can't find these relevant Ids. I want to avoid this situation.

**So my question is**, *is there any way to achieve a function like this, like using two Ehcache servers or something?* i.e. When one is in use, the other one can load the data from MongoDB. When the update is done, switch it to the updated one. So every day when the MongoDB data updated, and I have to update the Ehcache data, it won't influence my current cache. That's just a thought I have. Another thought is something like a SQL transaction. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I see two ways.

One is to use an application lock. When you are ready to reload the cache, you block access to it and do it. There is no way to clear all caches are the same time. The problem is that everything will be blocked during the update.

The other way is to use an other cache. So you load the new cache with the new data and then swap the new cache and the expired one. The problem with this solution is that at a given moment you will take twice the memory since both caches are in memory.

Comment: Yes. I prefer the first solution cuz memory cost too much after all. Thank you!